# Setting Security to Web Services in Apache Tomcat

Tags: web-services, security, apache, tomcat

Does anyone knows how to set up the security to a web service in apache tomcat? =D

Answer (score 0):

to answer the last @(Rhigo HR) question, on this guide (@Paul 's ref.), it says

"In this way, the authentication is declarative rather than programmatic like this – application authentication in JAX-WS"

with a link, the link give us an alternate solution programmatic, I think this solve your question. (I know the post is old, but too many people still have problems like this, just like me :) )